# Retrieving MySQL results from two tables excluding what is common in both tables in a specific column

Tags: mysql

I am trying get results from a MySQL database excluding everything common in both tables from a specific column, but I am falling short. This is what I have which is not working out for me.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE_A 
  JOIN TABLE_B
 WHERE TABLE_A.id_A  != TABLE_B.id_B
 GROUP BY TABLE_A.id_A;
```

This is how the tables are structured.

**TABLE_A**

| Id_A | Data_TA_1 | Data_TA_2 | Data_TA_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | int | varchar | int |
| 2 | int | varchar | int |
| 3 | int | varchar | int |
| 4 | int | varchar | int |
| 5 | int | varchar | int |
| 6 | int | varchar | int |
| 7 | int | varchar | int |
| 8 | int | varchar | int |

and

**TABLE_B**

| Id_B | Data_TB_1 | Data_TB_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | int | int |
| 6 | int | int |
| 7 | int | int |

I am trying to get the query to **ONLY** output results from **TABLE_A** **excluding** what is **common** to both **TABLE_A** and **TABLE_B**. (**3,6 and 7**).
In other words, I need the query to **ONLY** give me results (**1,2,4,5,8…**) from **TABLE_A**

Note: **TABLE_A** and **TABLE_B** don’t have equal amounts of columns or the same column names.

Comment: I have removed the tag [tag:sql-server] as your title says MySQL, and thus I *assume* you are using MySQL *not* SQL Server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a `NOT IN` clause:

```sql
SELECT a.*
  FROM TABLE_A a
 WHERE a.Id_A NOT IN (
          SELECT b.Id_B
            FROM TABLE_B b
       )
```

Alternatively, use a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```sql
SELECT a.*
  FROM TABLE_A a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT *
            FROM TABLE_B b
           WHERE b.Id_B = a.Id_A
       )
```

Comment: Thank you for the support. Can you please explain what i was doing wrong? i still don't get it

Comment: @Dslide You are doing a `CROSS JOIN`, so *every* record in TABLE_A is compared to *every* record in TABLE_B, so *(ignoring the `GROUP BY`)* the result in `(Id_A,Id-B) = [ (1,3), (1,6), (1,7), (2,3), (2,6), (2,7), (3,6), (3,7), (4,3), (4,6), (4,7), ... ]` where the `(3,3)` combo is filtered out.

Comment: I see now. Thanks